# Execute code block if stage fails, but proceed with other stages

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

We would like to send an email if a stage fails. The stage should be marked as unstable, but overall build result should not be affected by the result of this stage. This is the code snippet that we are using:

```java
stage("Stage 1")
{
    catchError(buildResult: 'SUCCESS', stageResult: 'UNSTABLE')
    {
        sh 'scriptThatCanExitWithStatus1.sh'
    }
}
```

It works fine, but we are not able to define the code that should be executed if shell script fails. How can we execute custom error handling block of code if `scriptThatCanExitWithStatus1.sh` fails (ex. send an email to sys admin)?

Answer (score 1):

This is how I solved the problem:

```java
stage("Stage 1")
{
    success = false

    catchError(buildResult: 'SUCCESS', stageResult: 'UNSTABLE')
    {
        sh 'scriptThatCanExitWithStatus1.sh'
        success = true
    }

    if (!success) {
        // send mail
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use try catch in a script block and re-throw the error after performing the error handling. See example below:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('1') {
            steps {
                sh 'exit 0'
            }
        }
        stage('2') {
            steps {
                catchError(buildResult: 'SUCCESS', stageResult: 'FAILURE') {
                    script {
                        try {
                            sh "exit 1"
                        } catch (e) {
                            echo 'send email'
                            throw e
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        stage('3') {
            steps {
                sh 'exit 0'
            }
        }
    }
}
```